# Проблема с Polylang и Custom Taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress

использую для Custom Post Type , Custom Taxonomy. Все отлично работало, ибо таксономи я вывел на главную страницу
Получил все таксоны с помощью функции

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( [
          'taxonomy' => 'types',
          'hide_empty' => false,
        ] );
```

Все отлично работает. Но так как я использую Polylang надо было переводить таксономии. В настройках Polylang поставил галочку
*Activate languages and translations for custom taxonomies.*

После этого таксономи не работают
Если вызываю

```
var_dump($terms)
```

Получаю пустой массив. Убираю галочку с перевода таксономи, снова работает. Кто с этим сталкивался и за чего может быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте явно указать язык, на котором нужно получить термины в массиве опций. Например так:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( [
          'taxonomy' => 'types',
          'hide_empty' => false,
          'lang' => 'ru'
        ] );
```

Или указать пустое значение, чтобы получить все языки:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( [
          'taxonomy' => 'types',
          'hide_empty' => false,
          'lang' => ''
        ] );
```